# The best way to save input files so they will be executed when called by Get

Tags: programming

I have a very simple program which computes fixed points for SIR model:

```
s1 = \[CapitalLambda] (1 - s) -   \[Beta]  s i  ;
i1 = i (\[Beta]  s - \[CapitalLambda] - \[Gamma]) ;
r1 = \[Gamma] i  - \[CapitalLambda] r;
dyn = {s1, i1, r1}; var = {s, i, r};
Print["Check sum ", Total[dyn] // FullSimplify]
dyn
```

I wanted like to call it from a main file:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
AppendTo[$Path, Directory];
Clear["Global`*"];
Get["SIR.wl"];
dyn
so = Solve[Thread[dyn == 0], var]
```

in which  I could then replace the SIR by other epidemic models. The documentation suggests using Get, but this is incomplete.  To have the file  executed, it is necessary that SIR  be saved not as .nb, but as .wl file, otherwise it is not executed, and no output is passed to the Main. Now there seem to be several choices on how to save (.wl, .m, .wls, and also text files, in which case the extension is ignored). How to choose between these options? Thanks for your help

Comment: "The documentation suggests using Get, but this is incomplete." Please say which part of the documentation you are referring to (link). Also, you seem to have answered your original question about 15 minutes after posting it, are you sure you want to keep the question open?

Comment: Documentation for Get says: "<<name
reads in a file, evaluating each expression in it and returning the last one.  This is incorrect, it does  not work if the name is  an .nb file.  I have been hoping for a SIMPLE  explanation of when to use .wl, .m, .wls, and  text files for a long time (in between the overly simplified, incorrect documentation,  and too detailed ones), so even though I fixed  my program by trial and error, I want to maintain the question.

Comment: Thanks, I get it. It's a complicated question, so it can't have a simple answer :)